# WebGL, and mat4.perspective function not working

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a problem with the code for trying to display a simple triangle object and simple square object. When I run the code, neither object appears. The problem is with the mat4.perspective function and possibly the parameters. Here is the code with the error:

```
    function drawScene() {
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        var rads=45*(Math.PI/180);
        mat4.perspective(pMatrix, rads, gl.viewportWidth/gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);
        alert("this works");
        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);


        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix [3.0, 0.0, 0.0]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
    }
```

The JS alert I added works before the mat4.perspective line but not afterwards so I know the problem lies in this line. Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong and how to correct the problem?

Comment: Do you get any errors in dev tools ?

Comment: Yes, it says mat4 is not defined. Once on a previous line: var mvMatrix = mat4.create(); and once on the mat4.perspective line

Comment: Maybe `mat4 is not defined` have you included `gl-matrix` prior to your javascript?

Comment: Yes, near the top of the <head> section is <script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

I have a working setup into which I placed your code ... this line is suspect

```
mat4.perspective(pMatrix, rads, gl.viewportWidth/gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);
```

here is mine which you might try

```
mat4.perspective(FoV , gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
```

where

```
var FoV = 20.0;
```

which controls field-of-view

Here is a WebGL project I wrote which implements keyboard + mouse
interactions to zoom/pan/slide about ... feel free to pillage at will
NOTE - it was my first usage of javascript/WebGL so take it with a grain of salt, but it does scream !

```
https://github.com/scottstensland/webgl-3d-animation
```

Comment: Since glMatrix version 2.0 the first parameter is *always* the output parameter making the `mat4.perspective` call of the OP correct.

Comment: So does this mean I should upgrade to a newer version of glMatrix? Could be that the create and perspective functions are not defined in 0.9.5. If I need to upgrade, which version should I use and where could I find it?

Comment: My setup uses 0.9.5 which has both create and perspective and works fine.  Can U park your entire codebase as some jsfiddle so we can t/s it ?